# Is it possible for excel to check the latest possible date in an array?

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: Example]

As seen in example table, the balance will only be shown in the table when a transaction is made. Before that, the balance will stay the same as previous month.

E.g: August 2021 is not shown in the table, as no transaction is made in that month. Hence August 2021 balance should be equal to previous available balance, which is June 2021.

However, a transaction is made in Oct 2021. Hence Oct 2021 balance should be equal to the Oct 2021 balance.

3 transactions are made in Nov. Hence Nov balance should be equal to the balance shown at the latest Nov transaction.

I'm trying to make a table with each month in a year and pick up the correct balance from the example table. However, if I'm using index match, I can only pick up those month where an transaction is made, and not Aug 2021 for example.

Is it possible for excel to determine and auto-regress to the latest available balance?

Comment: It's not exactly what you're looking for, but one built-in option is using a pivot table, grouped by `MM`, where `MM` has "show items with no data" enabled (to include months with no data). Then set your `Balance` field to Show Values As > Running Total In > `MM` (to use previous month's balance).

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to solve this problem.

If you insist on a formula, let's construct it together.

The [**MATCH() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) will do most of the work. It has one amazing property:
[image: MATCH finds the largest value]

So, with the help of MATCH() we will find the number of the desired row, and with the help of INDEX() we will get the desired value:
`=INDEX(<Balance_range>;MATCH(...))`

MATCH() will look for a date value formatted as 2012-07. This is easy to do with the [**TEXT() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c): `TEXT(<Date_cell>;"YYYY-MM")`

The most difficult part of the task is to convert the alphabetic names of the months into their numerical values, the ordinal numbers of the months. And MATCH() will do this too:
`MATCH(<Cell_from_MM>;   {"Jan"\"Feb"\"Mar"\"Apr"\"May"\"Jun"\"Jul"\"Aug"\"Sep"\"Oct"\"Nov"\"Dec"};0)`

So, with formula

`{=$B$3:$B$12&"-"&TEXT(MATCH($A$3:$A$12;   {"Jan"\"Feb"\"Mar"\"Apr"\"May"\"Jun"\"Jul"\"Aug"\"Sep"\"Oct"\"Nov"\"Dec"};0);"00")`

we can get array of year-month from columns **MM** and **YYYY**

```
MM  YYYY    Formula
Dec 2020    2020-12
Jun 2021    2021-06
Oct 2021    2021-10
Nov 2021    2021-11
Nov 2021    2021-11
Nov 2021    2021-11
Dec 2021    2021-12
Dec 2021    2021-12
Jan 2022    2022-01
```

It is in this array that the MATCH() function will try to find a suitable value.

Now let's just collect all these parts into one formula:

`{=INDEX($C$3:$C$12;MATCH(TEXT(F3;"YYYY-MM");$B$3:$B$12&"-"&TEXT(MATCH($A$3:$A$12;   {"Jan"\"Feb"\"Mar"\"Apr"\"May"\"Jun"\"Jul"\"Aug"\"Sep"\"Oct"\"Nov"\"Dec"};0);"00")))}`

This is an array formula, the input must be completed with the key combination **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**

The result might be like this:
[image: Result table]

Here in cell F3 the value is 2021-01-01, and in F4 `=EOMONTH(F3;1)`